# Political rule by council

Tags: political-theory, political-system, form-of-government

What is the name of the political system ruled by nonelected council? Similar to corporate rule. I call it councilism, but looking for better name.

Comment: This is going to depend somewhat on the selection method for the council. For example a group of priests might be called a theocracy, or military leaders a junta. Not that those nouns are universally accepted to have a single meaning of course.

Comment: People who already have de facto influence are selected. For example, the rich business people. The variation of Trilateral Commission with direct political power and council based decision making. Is a better name than oligarchy possible?

Comment: "Illuminati"? :)

Comment: Plutocracy, i.e. rule by the rich?

Answer (score 9):

In the generalities, a political system ruled by a few persons is an oligarchy:

> [Oligarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligarchy) (from Greek [ὀλιγαρχία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3D*o%3Aentry%20group%3D22%3Aentry%3Do%29ligarxi%2Fa) (oligarkhía); from [ὀλίγος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Do)li%2Fgos) (olígos), meaning 'few', and [ἄρχω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Da)%2Frxw) (arkho), meaning 'to rule or to command') is a form of power structure in which power rests with a small number of people.

After that, there are a number of specific categorization that can be applied to the group, depending on extenuating circumstances.

Comment: I took the liberty of linking the Greek words to the lexical entries.  Hope that's ok.  Excellent answer!